# c# dynamically created buttons not firing click event

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I added a asp.net table to my webform. Dynamically added table rows and cells in the table using a foreach statement. 
The last cell of every row has a button in it. Along with the button, i created a click event.

When I click the button i want to send the page to the "Default.aspx" form.

But when i run the application, clicking the button just refreshes the pages.

Here is the code:

```
    int i = 1;
    Button btn;
    foreach (SP_GetEmpAgenda a in agenda)
    {
        TableRow r = new TableRow();
        AgendaTable.Rows.Add(r);

        TableCell present = new TableCell();
        present.Text = a.Arrived.ToString();
        AgendaTable.Rows[i].Cells.Add(present);


        TableCell buttonCell = new TableCell();
        buttonCell.Width = 200;
        buttonCell.Height = 50;

        btn = new Button();
        btn.Text = "Check-In";
        btn.CssClass = "btn btn-outline-dark";
        btn.Click += (s, e) => { Response.Redirect("Default.aspx"); };

        buttonCell.Controls.Add(btn);

        AgendaTable.Rows[i].Cells.Add(buttonCell);

        i++;
    }
```

The click event is not responding it just refreshes the page. But when i create a single button normally outside this method in the Page_Load event, the button works properly.

How can I do this with the buttons i have created dynamically ??

Comment: You should use anchor link for redirection. It won't refresh the page

Comment: Move "Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");" to the next line, add a breakpoint and debug your application. Does it stop?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya That worked thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned dynamically added control should be created inside page_load so that their view state will persist as well. If you create in !IsPostBack then also there will be issue. So create in page_load without any if condition

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `ID` and `runat = "server"` attribute while creating button dynamically.

```
 btn = new Button();
 btn.ID = "NewBtn";
 btn.Text = "Check-In";
 btn.CssClass = "btn btn-outline-dark";
 btn.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
 btn.Click += new EventHandler(NewBtn_Click);
```

Also add your button click event separately and move your `Response.Redirect()` code to it.

```
protected void NewBtn_Click(object sender, EventHandler e)
{
  Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
}
```

OR

If still it don't work add `UseSubmitBehavior="false"` as button property which will do ASP.NET postback and not client's browser submit request.